# KD tree - Difficulty in understanding a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, tree

I was reading a kd tree implementation in C.Here is some parts of it.The problem is in findmedian function.I dont understand the implementation of

```
*md = start +(end-start)/2;
```

......  -> Other irrelevant lines of code

```
struct kd_node_t
{
    double x[3];
    struct kd_node_t *left, *right;
};
struct kd_node_t* findmedian(struct kd_node_t *start, struct kd_node_t *end, int idx)
{
......
struct kd_node_t *p, *store, *md = start + (end - start) / 2;
......
}
```

Comment: difference of two pointers = number of elements between them

Comment: Median isn't what is at the middle of the node? start + (end - start)/2 give's you exactly that.

Comment: start + (end-start)/2 == start + length/2 = start + middle

Comment: @IanMedeiros but pointer refers to a structure.So how can they be subtracted

Comment: They can, pointers are just values which represent a memory location... If there is a meaningful value half-way at the position `start + (end - start)/2` depends on the implementation of the algorithm...

Comment: It's pointer arithmetic: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html. Probably the"irrelevant lines of codes" are setting up te memory to aways store the kd-tree nodes ordered. Witch means that the pointer to the middle of any level of the tree is aways the median value.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, what is implemented here is just the "half-way between the two pointers" `start` and `end`. If the implementation takes care that there is a meaningful value at this position in memory (which might be a median) then you're lucky, otherwise you get garbage...

Comment: I dont think that's happening.Just see the find_median code at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/K-d_tree#C . Thanks